# Can I use CSS to change header content when window in minimized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to mimic a website design from a clothing brand to get a better understanding of HTML CSS. I want to know if the header content can be changed when the window size in a smaller view, through CSS, or if I'll need JS.

[As you can see in full screen mode, there are two sections: category and support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1GAz.jpg)
[But in minimized view the header says: Download the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh7tF.png)

I couldn't find any solution online so I'm posting here hoping for some answers. Below is my code if it is of any help:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Souled Store</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="TSS Clone Header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="TSS general.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first-header">
            <div class="outfit-selection-by-gender">
                <div class="women-section">
                    <button class="women">
                        WOMEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="men-section">
                    <button class="men">
                        MEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="kids-section">
                    <button class="kids">
                        KIDS
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="support-section">
                <div class="order-tracking-section">
                    <button class="order-tracking-button">
                        TRACK ORDER
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="contact-us-section">
                    <button class="contact-us-button">
                        CONTACT US
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="app-download-section">
                    <button class="app-download-button">
                        DOWNLOAD APP
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.first-header {
    height: 45px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap:;
}

.outfit-selection-by-gender {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: start;
}

.women {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.men {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: none;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.kids {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.support-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}

.app-download-button {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.contact-us-button {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.order-tracking-button {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: when a window is minimized, generally that means it's not visible at all - are you perhaps referring to responsive design dependant on window size - this is usually done using CSS media queries on properties such as min-width max-width or even orientation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: CSS cannot change content. It can only style it. If you actually want to swap out content you need JS.

Comment: @Paulie_D You don't necessary need JS. It's definitely easier, but CSS has media queries where you can also write extra lines to swap content.

Comment: @EagertoLearn No. You can't swap content with a media query. You can hide or reveal content that is already there but that is not the same as swapping it in or out of the DOM

Comment: @Paulie_D It depends on the meaning of "swap content". Dynamically hide/show existing page content (can be done with CSS) or dynamically adding/removing content in the DOM (requires JavaScript.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your HTML needs to have the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Using ONLY CSS, I used media query to toggle HTML element display. Screen widths of 600px and less will see the `mobile-banner`. At the same time, this will hide the class element of `first-header`.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Souled Store</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first-header" id="banner">
            <div class="outfit-selection-by-gender">
                <div class="women-section">
                    <button class="women">
                        WOMEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="men-section">
                    <button class="men">
                        MEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="kids-section">
                    <button class="kids">
                        KIDS
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="support-section">
                <div class="order-tracking-section">
                    <button class="order-tracking-button">
                        TRACK ORDER
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="contact-us-section">
                    <button class="contact-us-button">
                        CONTACT US
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="app-download-section">
                    <button class="app-download-button">
                        DOWNLOAD APP
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobile-banner">
            <span>
                Download Our App &amp; Get 10% Additional Cashback On All Orders
            </span>

            <button class="app-download-button">
                <span>
                    <!-- phone icon here -->
                </span>
                Open App
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS (this snippet includes only my changes)**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.app-download-button {
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px; /* placeholder space for phone icon, remove later */
}

.mobile-banner {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .first-header {
        display: none; /* hides elements with this class */
    }
    
    .mobile-banner {
        display: flex; /* displays elements with this class; flex */
    }
}
```

```css
.first-header {
    height: 45px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    /* column-gap:; */
}

.outfit-selection-by-gender {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: start;
}

.women {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.men {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: none;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.kids {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.support-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}

.app-download-button {
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px; /* placeholder space for phone icon, remove later */
}

.contact-us-button {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.order-tracking-button {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.mobile-banner {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .first-header {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .mobile-banner {
        display: flex;
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Souled Store</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first-header" id="banner">
            <div class="outfit-selection-by-gender">
                <div class="women-section">
                    <button class="women">
                        WOMEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="men-section">
                    <button class="men">
                        MEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="kids-section">
                    <button class="kids">
                        KIDS
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="support-section">
                <div class="order-tracking-section">
                    <button class="order-tracking-button">
                        TRACK ORDER
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="contact-us-section">
                    <button class="contact-us-button">
                        CONTACT US
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="app-download-section">
                    <button class="app-download-button">
                        DOWNLOAD APP
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobile-banner">
            <span>
                Download Our App &amp; Get 10% Additional Cashback On All Orders
            </span>

            <button class="app-download-button">
                <span>
                    <!-- phone icon -->
                </span>
                Open App
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `body { margin: 0; }` removes the whitespace between elements and the border of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

On my opinion and how I have understand  the question is that if you create and html and css if you create heading in side the body with out putting the font-size on you css style sheet the the heading will follow the screen size and example you are creating a mobile design website by using @media so the px you want the screen to be is what makes you header to be more minimum or maximum on you code thank if there is any thing else please ask me

```css
.first-header {
    height: 45px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    /* column-gap:; */
}

.outfit-selection-by-gender {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: start;
}

.women {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.men {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: none;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.kids {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}

.support-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}

.app-download-button {
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px; /* placeholder space for phone icon, remove later */
}

.contact-us-button {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.order-tracking-button {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(237, 45, 47);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.mobile-banner {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .first-header {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .mobile-banner {
        display: flex;
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Souled Store</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first-header" id="banner">
            <div class="outfit-selection-by-gender">
                <div class="women-section">
                    <button class="women">
                        WOMEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="men-section">
                    <button class="men">
                        MEN
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="kids-section">
                    <button class="kids">
                        KIDS
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="support-section">
                <div class="order-tracking-section">
                    <button class="order-tracking-button">
                        TRACK ORDER
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="contact-us-section">
                    <button class="contact-us-button">
                        CONTACT US
                    </button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="app-download-section">
                    <button class="app-download-button">
                        DOWNLOAD APP
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobile-banner">
            <span>
                Download Our App &amp; Get 10% Additional Cashback On All Orders
            </span>

            <button class="app-download-button">
                <span>
                    <!-- phone icon -->
                </span>
                Open App
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```